# Lift sanctions on/off Russia

Tags: prepositions

Despite the prepositions opposite to each other, I suppose that either sentence is correct. Of course, I have googled, and the first is way more common, but what will a native grammar-savvy say?

Any objections?

> Lift sanctions on Russia
>
> Lift sanctions off Russia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good question.  Your observation is true in that lifting sanctions on Russia will result in sanctions be lifted off Russia.  Prepositional mayhem!

What is unspoken and merely implied in the first sentence is

> "Lift the sanctions [*that were placed*] on Russia [*off of Russia*]."

So you are still lifting sanctions "off".

Similarly with your second sentence,

> "Lift the sanctions off [*of*] Russia [*that were placed on Russia*]."

As you observe both are correct and the first usage is far more common.

When we lift something we can either lift it off something or we may lift it onto something.  To lift something 'on' something means you were on the object while lifting the subject.  "He lifted his beer mug on the roof of his house," means he was standing on the roof of his house and lifting a beer mug.

Comment: *Sanction* itself can be confusing as a [contranym](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/words-own-opposites); I'm waiting for a headline today to read *U.K. sanctions Russia; U.S. sanctions U.K. action*.